# When application is closed some features of fcm notification not working

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm using fcm for push notification.
when app is open and notification received , notification work correctly.
but when app is closed and notification is recieved, some features like vibrate , sound , addaction , ... not working.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FullscreenActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String urlAddress = "https://cafebazaar.ir/";
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent2.setPackage("com.farsitel.bazaar");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Notification notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.macanads)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(Integer.parseInt(color))
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_directions,"بروزرسانی",pendingIntent2)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    }


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder);
}
```

Comment: What does your PUSH message look like?  Is it data only?  Also, assume I you have a service with intent filter for `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT` in your Android manifest?

Comment: yes is data only.my manifest : `code` <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service> `code`

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved.you must not put JSON key 'notification' in your request to firebase API but instead use 'data'

To make firebase library to call your onMessageReceived() in the following cases

App in foreground

App in background

App has been killed

you must not put JSON key 'notification' in your request to firebase API but instead use 'data', see below.

The following message will not call your onMessageReceived() when your app is in the background or killed, and you can't customize your notification.